# I can't generate an XML file larger than 25.6 MB from IIS (win 2016) with asp classic

Tags: iis-10

Using the "CreateTextFile" ASP object I can't create an XML larger than 25.6 MB.
The script in ASP that reads about 50,000 records on SQL Express runs regularly but stops the xlm file when the file arrives at this size.
No error is generated.
I've tried everything on IIS configurations, but I can't go beyond this limit.
Do you have any ideas?

This is code source: `

```
Dim OggFile, origine, OggTextStream
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strPath = Server.MapPath("/")  & "/csv/file/kijiji" 
if fs.FolderExists(strPath)=False then
fs.CreateFolder(strPath) 

'elimina vecchi file
if fs.FileExists(strPath & "/prodotti_kijiji.xml") then
fs.DeleteFile(strPath & "/prodotti_kijiji.xml")
fs.DeleteFile(strPath & "/prodotti_kijiji.zip")
'  Response.End()
end if

qry_gia_esportati="SELECT * FROM kijiji_controlloID"
rs1.Open qry_gia_esportati
Do Until rs1.EOF
IDkijiji=IDkijiji & "," & rs1("IDkijiji")
rs1.MoveNext
loop
rs1.Close
IDkijiji=IDkijiji & ","


qry_prodotto="SELECT " _
& " magazzino.IDmagazzino, magazzino.titolo, magazzino.descrizione_breve, magazzino.descrizione_lunga, magazzino.prezzo, magazzino.IDcategoria, magazzino.codice, magazzino.data_prezzo," _
& " produttori.ragione_sociale as produttore," _
& " distributori.ragione_sociale as distributore," _
& " categorie.categoria, categorie.categoria_uk, categorie.categoria_de, categorie.categoria_kijiji," _
& " iva.valore_iva," _
& " aree.area, aree.area_uk, aree.area_de, aree.idarea" _
& " FROM ((((magazzino " _
& " LEFT JOIN produttori ON magazzino.IDproduttore = produttori.IDproduttore)" _
& " LEFT JOIN distributori ON magazzino.IDdistributore = distributori.IDdistributore)" _
& " LEFT JOIN categorie ON magazzino.IDcategoria = categorie.IDcategoria)" _
& " LEFT JOIN iva ON magazzino.IDiva = iva.IDiva)" _
& " LEFT JOIN aree ON categorie.IDarea = aree.IDarea" _
& " WHERE (((magazzino.disponibile)=1) AND ((magazzino.visibile)=0) AND ((magazzino.IDcategoria)<>256) AND ((magazzino.IDcategoria)<>280) AND ((magazzino.IDcategoria)<>300) AND ((magazzino.titolo)<>'Nuovo prodotto') AND ((magazzino.pezzi)>0))" _
& " ORDER BY IDmagazzino ASC"
rs1.Open(qry_prodotto)
'comincia a scrivere nel file   

'crea il file xml e lo apre
file_percorso="/csv/file/kijiji/prodotti_kijiji.xml"
origine=server.Mappath(file_percorso)

fs.CreateTextFile (origine)
Set OggFile = fs.GetFile (origine)
Set OggTextStream = OggFile.OpenAsTextStream(2)
OggTextStream.WriteLine  "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>" 
OggTextStream.WriteLine  "<kijijipartners_xml>" 
 OggTextStream.WriteLine  "<annunci>" 


Do Until rs1.EOF


descrizione_lunga= TogliHtml(rs1("descrizione_lunga"))
if descrizione_lunga="" then descrizione_lunga= TogliHtml(rs1("descrizione_breve"))
titolo=TogliHtml(rs1("titolo"))
codice=rs1("codice")
IDchk="," & rs1("IDmagazzino") & ","

if instr(IDkijiji,IDchk)>0 then Enum_azione="Inserisci" else Enum_azione="Elimina"
if rs1("prezzo")>0 then
enum_tipo="SPECIFIED_AMOUNT"
prezzo=int(rs1("prezzo"))
Else
enum_tipo="PLEASE_CONTACT"
prezzo=""
End If
id_chk=id_chk & ", " & rs1("IDmagazzino")





OggTextStream.WriteLine  "<annuncio><azione>"& Enum_azione &"</azione><id>" & rs1("IDmagazzino") & "</id><titolo><![CDATA[" & chk_tit(titolo) & "]]></titolo><descrizione><![CDATA[" & chk_tit(descrizione_lunga) & "]]></descrizione><categorie><categoria codice = """ & rs1("categoria_kijiji") & """></categoria></categorie><data_pubblicazione>" & rs1("data_prezzo") & "</data_pubblicazione><url_redirect><![CDATA[" & Application("startengine_indirizzosito") & "/store/_it/prodotto.asp?idp=" & rs1("IDmagazzino") & "]]></url_redirect><luoghi><comune codice = """ & codice_istat & """></comune></luoghi><salario><tipo_prezzo>"& enum_tipo & "</tipo_prezzo><ammontare>" & prezzo & "</ammontare></salario><email>" & Application("StartEngine_mail_gestore") & "</email><telefono>" & Replace(Application("startengine_tel"),"+39","") & "</telefono><venditore codice = ""2""></venditore>" 

if fs.FileExists(server.Mappath("/") & "/archivio/fotografie/" & rs1("IDmagazzino") & ".jpg") then
OggTextStream.WriteLine  "<pictures>" 
OggTextStream.WriteLine  "<picture_url>" & Application("startengine_indirizzosito") & "/archivio/fotografie/" & rs1("IDmagazzino") & ".jpg</picture_url>" 
OggTextStream.WriteLine  "</pictures>" 
end if
OggTextStream.WriteLine  "</annuncio>" 
rs1.MoveNext
loop
rs1.close
OggTextStream.WriteLine  "</annunci>" 
OggTextStream.WriteLine  "</kijijipartners_xml>" 
OggTextStream.close
if id_chk<>"" then 
id_chk = right(id_chk,len(id_chk)-1)
End If
'svuoto la tabella di controllo con i nuovi dati
qry_del="DELETE FROM kijiji_controlloID "
rs1.Open qry_del
a=Split(id_chk,",") 
for each y in a
qry_insert="INSERT INTO kijiji_controlloID VALUES ("& y &");"
rs1.Open qry_insert
next

' creo file .ZIP
dim zip, filepath
filepath = "/csv/file/kijiji/prodotti_kijiji.zip"
set zip = new aspZip
zip.OpenArquieve(filepath)
zip.Add(file_percorso)
zip.CloseArquieve()
set zip = nothing
```

`

Answer (score 1):

To troubleshoot this issue please follow the below steps:

1)open the iis manager and select the site from the connection pane.

2)Click on the ASP feature.

[image]

3)Expand the Limits Properties icon, and change the value in the “maxRequestEntityAllowed” to a value larger than 200000.

[image]

maxRequestEntityAllowed use to control how much can be accepted in a request. This is handled by the maxRequestEntityAllowed attribute.

```
 <configuration>
   <system.webServer>
     <asp>
       <limits maxRequestEntityAllowed="200000" />
     </asp>
   <system.webServer>
 <configuration>
```

4)Click the APPLY button. and restart the iis server after doing changes.

You could also try to set the maxAllowedContentLength which controls how much data is allowed to be sent in a response.

```
 <configuration>
   <system.webServer>
     <security>
       <requestFiltering>
         <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="30000000" />
       </requestFiltering>
     </security>
   </system.webServer>
 </configuration>
```

[ASP Limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/asp/limits)

[Request Limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits/)

Set the limit value larger than the file size.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the solution, this is the setting of the web.config:

Comment: <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />

Comment: did you try to set the asp setting which is mention in the post?